# Using ion() from pylab causes matplotlib to hang

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I'm using Enthought's 32 bit python distribution for mac.

If I try:

```
$ ipython
In [1] from pylab import *
In [2] ion()
In [3] plot([1,2],[1,2])
```

The figure is created, but python freezes while trying to plot.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

plotting by running in `ipython --pylab` works fine

Comment: maybe `from matplotlib.pyplot import plot` but it looks like you should get that with `from pylab import *` what happens if you change to `from pylab import plot,ion`

Comment: same thing. The figure is created but it freezes after that

Comment: i dunno im on windows... but it works fine for me ... (ipython prompt usually looks like `In [1]:` and normal interpreter usually looks like `>>>` ... wonder if you maybe pointing ipython to normal python?(although it seems to work fine also in normal python for me...))

Comment: no, I was just lazy and didn't type the `In [etc]`, but I should change that. Thank you for your reply

Comment: @JoranBeasley What backend is matplotlib running for you?

Comment: yeah Ive never been able to get wx backend to work right for matplotlib... but its just something trivial im missing im sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the 'WXAgg' backend and I switched to 'macosx' this seems to fix the problem

```
In [1]: import matplotlib

In [2]: matplotlib.get_backend()
Out[2]: 'WXAgg'

In [3]: matplotlib.use('macosx')

In [4]: matplotlib.get_backend()
Out[4]: 'MacOSX'

In [5]: from pylab import *

In [6]: ion()

In [7]: plot([1,2]) # now works fine
```