# Matplotlib interactive mode not working on win 7

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda

This file should work, but it doesn't:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

pyplot.ion()
pyplot.plot(range(10))

raw_input('Press return to close')
```

The plot window appears, the inside is white and the hourglass cursor is shown.
The text is printed in the shell, and hitting return closes the empty plot window.

I can plot from ipython, but this has to run from a file.
Exactly the same problem as [Using ion() from pylab causes matplotlib to hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827969/using-ion-from-pylab-causes-matplotlib-to-hang) , but the solution doesn't help me.

I am using Qt4Agg, by default. I haven't changed any settings, it is a fresh Anaconda install.

I don't think this is Anaconda specific, I had exactly the same problem some time ago with a normal Python install, but I don't remember the solution.

I recently upgraded Matplotlib to 1.3.1 np18py27_1

```
Current conda install:

             platform : win-32
        conda version : 3.0.6
       python version : 2.7.6.final.0
     root environment : C:\Anaconda  (writable)
  default environment : C:\Anaconda
     envs directories : C:\Anaconda\envs
        package cache : C:\Anaconda\pkgs
         channel URLs : http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-32/
                        http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-32/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False
```

Comment: I had problems on windows with `ion()` as well while my code worked fine on linux. For me it helped to introduce a very short pause which enabled windows to not show a white window. The code I needed to include was: `pylab.pause(1.e-6)`. Does this work for you as well?

Comment: When I put the pylab.pause(1e-6) after the plot, the plot appears, but is not interactive. Very strange. Do you have any idea what is going on?

Comment: In what sense is it not interactive? It will require you to plot more than you provided in your code. After each plot you should have `pyplot.draw()`. With this piece of code the interactive plot is updated with the new data.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. With interactive I meant that I can't interact with the plot anymore. When I do ion, plot, raw_input, I get a white window with nothing. ion, pause, plot, raw_input is the same. ion, plot, pause, raw_input draws the plot, but the window then freezes and I can't zoom. When I pause for 10 seconds, I can zoom for 10 seconds, and then it freezes.

Comment: This is strange, because the code in my question is very basic, I've been using that for many years. It works on other machines, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was embarrassingly simple,

```
ipython qtconsole --matplotlib
```

The "trick" is to add the option --matplotlib.
Running the IPython-qtconsole from the Anaconda launcher omits this, I don't know why. 
At least it should give a warning on pyplot.ion() if it doesn't support interactive plotting.

Answer (score 1):

If it fixed your problem to call a different back-end, you can make this a permanent change by changing the `matplotlibrc` file.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure where this file would be in windows.

When you do find it, line 32 sets the back-end used:

```
#### CONFIGURATION BEGINS HERE

# the default backend; one of GTK GTKAgg GTKCairo GTK3Agg GTK3Cairo
# CocoaAgg FltkAgg MacOSX QtAgg Qt4Agg TkAgg WX WXAgg Agg Cairo GDK PS
# PDF SVG Template
# You can also deploy your own backend outside of matplotlib by
# referring to the module name (which must be in the PYTHONPATH) as
# 'module://my_backend'
backend      : <Whatever works for you>
```

This will allow you to run it from a file - outside of ipython

Comment: I've tried the backends from matplotlib.rcsetup.all_backends, most are not available or have the same issue. I fear this is a problem with the installation, maybe it is defective somehow. Unfortunately this is a machine that runs very specialized and expensive hardware that interfaces with the python installation in a very unfortunate way (installs files directly into install), so I can't just re-install python.

Comment: interesting, can you set up a virtual environment - using [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html)?

Comment: The OP is using Anaconda, so should use `conda create` to create a separate environment.

Comment: The new environment didn't do it either, a command line option was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want something like this. It works fine under linux. Since the pause of 1.e-6 seconds is included it should also work on windows.

```
import sys
import select
from matplotlib import pyplot


def heardEnter():
    i,o,e = select.select([sys.stdin],[],[],0.0001)
    for s in i:
        if s == sys.stdin:
            input = sys.stdin.readline()
            return True
    return False

pyplot.ion()
pyplot.pause(1.e-6)

print "Press enter to exit plotting"

cont = 1
while cont:
    pyplot.plot(range(10 + cont))
    pyplot.draw()

    cont += 1
    if heardEnter():
        cont = False
```

Comment: This caused a crash on windows, but thanks for the help.